# Get Base64 in object coming as string

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have a dout, how can i aceess this Object data and retreive the image in base64.
I noticed that it returns a string himself

```
const data = {
  image:"{\"base64\":\"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\r\n\"}",
}
```

if i do `console.log(data.image)` it returns the string itself but i want base64 string only

Comment: You're doing something absolutely wrong. Why is your data a **string** instead of an Object with a property `base64` holding a base64 String? (and without the `\r\n`stuff at the end...)

Comment: this is the server response

Comment: You built the server-side response? The JSON in not encoded properly

Comment: no i did not someone else did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(you'll have to ask the backend dev to remove the `\n\r` in the end, or remove it yourself ) use `JSON.parse` to parse the `data.image` and get the `base64` key :

```js
const data = {
  image:"{\"base64\":\"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\"}",
}

const str = JSON.parse(data.image).base64

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Nice! But I was thinking, if the back-end didn't remove `\r\n`, wouldn't be possible to OP make a `.replace("\r\n","")` ?

Comment: @CalvinNunes yes he def can, the data belongs to him now on the front end and he can remove it using `replace` or `slice`  :P

Answer (score 1):

Before your backend guys fixes the JSON encoding you could

```js
const data = {
  image:"{\"base64\":\"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\r\n\"}",
}

const b64_retrieved = /([\/+\da-zA-Z]+={0,2}){7}/.exec(data.image)[0];
const mime_prefixed = b64 => `data:image/${{'i':'png','/':'jpeg','R':'gif','U':'webp'}[b64[0]]};base64,${b64}`;
const img = new Image();
img.src = mime_prefixed(b64_retrieved);
document.documentElement.appendChild(img);
```

after the backend guys fix their issue you could:

```js
const data = {
  "image": {
    "base64": "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"
  },
}

const mime_prefixed = b64 => `data:image/${{'i':'png','/':'jpeg','R':'gif','U':'webp'}[b64[0]]};base64,${b64}`;
const img = new Image();
img.src = mime_prefixed(data.image.base64);
document.documentElement.appendChild(img);
```

also, ask if they could pass you in the object like:

```
const data = {
  "image" : "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhZA... ...iESEAA7",
}
```

that would spare you the smart-guessing the MIME type etc...

```js
const data = {
  "image": "data:image/gif;base64,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",
};

const img = new Image();
img.src = data.image;
document.documentElement.appendChild(img);
```